# Prevent Do not mutate state directly. Use setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function to add item on bag. It's working pretty cool but I got a warning Do not mutate state directly. Use setState();

How can I use `this.setState()` instead use `this.state.bagList[item.id] = {...item};`

```
addToBag = (item) => {
 let itemFound = false;

 Object.keys(this.state.bagList).map((key) => {
  const bagItem = this.state.bagList[key];

  if(bagItem.id === item.id) {
    itemFound = true;
    bagItem.quantity++;
    return bagItem;

  } else {
    return bagItem;        
    }
 });

  if(!itemFound) {
   this.state.bagList[item.id] = {...item};
  }

 const newbagList = this.state.bagList;
 this.setState({ bagList: newbagList });
 localStorage.setItem("productsOnBag", JSON.stringify(newbagList));
 this.showBag();
}
```

I expect prevent this warning and mutate the state correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setState` in the following way to update `bagList` without the mutation.

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
  bagList: {
    ...prevState.bagList,
    [item.id]: {...item}
  }
}))
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

I tried some other approaches, but I solved the warnings just adding my state in a `const` and attributing the `{...item}`. Here is the code:

```
...

if(!itemFound) {
 const addItemToBagList = this.state.bagList;
 addItemToBagList[item.id] = {...item };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is in the order of your code.
You are modifying state directly here:

```
   if(!itemFound) {
   this.state.bagList[item.id] = {...item};
  }
```

That's why it's throwing an error.
You should first create `newbagList`, and **after** that modify it and  `this.setState({ bagList: newbagList });`